# My app crashes when trying to create a list of Bypasses

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create bypasses list(in cardviw)
This is how i tried to add bypasses to byPassesList:

```
val bypassListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val bypassList: MutableList<Bypass> = mutableListOf()
        for (employeeSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val employeeEmail = employeeSnapshot.key.toString()
            for (streetSnapshot in employeeSnapshot.children) {
                val streetName = streetSnapshot.key.toString()
                for (bypassSnapshot in streetSnapshot.children) {
                    val houseNumber = bypassSnapshot.key.toString()
                    val bypass = bypassSnapshot.getValue(Bypass::class.java)
                    bypass?.let {
                        it.userEmail = employeeEmail ?: ""
                        it.street = streetName ?: ""
                        it.houseNumber = houseNumber ?: ""
                        bypassList.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val recyclerView = binding.rvBypasses
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@BypassesList)
        layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        val adapter = BypassAdapter(bypassList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ошибка бд", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
val bypassesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bypasses")
bypassesRef.addValueEventListener(bypassListener)
```

And if i try to start my actvity with Bypasses list, i have this(Logs from Logcat):

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.sellerhelper, PID: 4295
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.sellerhelper.Bypass

Class for Bypasses looks like this:

```
data class Bypass(
    var userEmail: String = "",
    var street: String = "",
    var houseNumber: String = ""
)
```

How i can fix that? Maybe i need to rewrite my Bypass class to different way? I tried to change type of fields userEmail, street, houseNumber to ArrayList, but it didn't work. Sry for dumb question:)

Comment: From the error message is seems like you have an array under each child node of street snapshot. Can you edit your question to include an example of the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that the code you shared processes? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

So, i fixed that, a problem was in `val bypass = bypassSnapshot.getValue(Bypass::class.java)`
I changed `bypassSnapshot` to `employeeSnapshot`(the first snapshot in cycles).

I think the problem was that there was not enough data in the last snapshot, so there was a type conflict